# Significance of kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast and kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big in core graphics

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am converting pdf's to images and displaying in ios using quartz 2d  api's. The bitmap image width and height will be arbitrary and will not necessarily  match the PDF's dimensions.

While most PDF's works just fine, for certain PDF's I only get an empty white image. The bitmap info currently used is `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast`. But if I change the bitmap info to `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` or `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big`, the image gets displayed.

I don't get how this works and why it did't work with just `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast`. Any thoughts ?

Full Code to convert the PDF to image

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Load PDF
    CFStringRef path = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "/Users/data/input.pdf", kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
    CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDoc, 1);
    
    
    // Create bitmap
    int width = 600;
    int height = 600;
    int stride = width * 4;
    char* buffer = malloc(stride * height);
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    const CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer,
                                                       width,
                                                       height,
                                                       8,
                                                       stride,
                                                       space,
                                                       // kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
                                                       // kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
                                                        kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pdfPage);
    
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *cgimage1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CFRelease(cgImage);
    CFRelease(context);
    
    // Display Image
    self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cgimage1];
    self.myImageView.center = self.view.center;
    self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.myImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 600, 600);
    [self.view addSubview:self.myImageView];
}


@end
```

Note: Even tried to save the image to disk and checked. The result was the same.

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(cgimage) writeToFile:@"/Users/data/output.png" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: If you want to know about how this affects your PDF to image conversion, you should show more code and details about how you do that conversion.  And maybe also explain how you know the rendered image is empty.

Comment: @JWWalker Added more code.